# Building Nav Bars with rollovers in DreamWeaver CS3

Tags: dreamweaver, rollovers

I'm working with Dreamweaver CS3. The question here is what part of the code (listed below) do I need to replicate to have my secondary nav bar utilize the on-click action?

FYI...DW has two menu options or auto insert items...one for roll over images and one for "navbar". DW will only allow you to use the 'navbar' item once per page

- the nav bar option builds all the rollover actions for you (listed below)
- the "rollover" option ONLY builds normal and over, but no click

I guess I really have two questions...the first is what part of the code do I need to insert manually, the second is what does the "MM_nbGroup" code mean?

```
"../photogallery.html" target="_top" onClick="MM_nbGroup('down','group1','photoMainNav','../images/buttons/photography_down.gif',1)" 
onMouseOver="MM_nbGroup('over','photoMainNav','../images/buttons/photography_over.gif','../images/buttons/photography_over.gif',1)" onMouseOut="MM_nbGroup('out')"><img src="../images/buttons/photography.gif"
```

Thanks for any help on this in advance!

Answer (score 0):

For anyone wondering the same thing, here's what I've found so far...

The 'insert' bar provided in DWCS3 doesn't allow for two 'inserted' menu bars on one page. However, the 'Behaviors' palette will allow you to add effective roll-overs with the "Set Nav Bar Image" option. Unfortunately (as far as I can tell) DWCS3 is not as smart as Adobe's GoLive was, in that it won't automatically fill in the appropriate items if you name your files correctly. Even still, you should name your images accordingly (xxx_over, xxx_down, etc) to keep it straight in your own head.

As for the MM_nbGroup question, best I can tell this is WYSIWYG code that ships with DWCS3 (the kind of stuff that really mifs some of you developers, sorry guys), as it names items by group # and doesn't seem to have any real relevance in the lexicon of html. I could be mistaken on this however, and am open to enlightenment on the topic if anyone can offer.